# Lenovo G50-70 Wifi keeps disconnecting Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, wireless, lenovo

EDIT:
Since  the last post I downgraded to 16.04 but it did not help to solve the issue either

I tried everything I could on the internet, but most of the answers were quite old and didn't work for me.

`sudo lshw -C network`

```
 *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: 74:29:af:15:97:ab
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.8.0-32-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.108 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:d0500000-d0503fff
```

```
grep [[:alnum:]] /sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/*
    /sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/ant_sel:0
    /sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/debug:0
    /sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/disable_watchdog:N
    /sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/fwlps:Y
    /sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/ips:Y
    /sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/msi:N
    /sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/swenc:N
    /sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/swlps:N
```

```
 $ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"eduroam"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point:         38:22:D6:81:FA:30   
      Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-33 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:89   Missed beacon:0`
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `grep [[:alnum:]] /sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/*`

Comment: Have you tried `echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` as it has been posted as an answer before going back a few years

Comment: Jeremy's suggestion didn't work.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from `iwconfig`